# mysql replication skip some batch delete query

Tags: mysql, replication

I set up a master slave mysql replication. I have an Event that run stored procedure and delete some rows (about 3500 rows). recently it skip some delete query in slave. for example it does not delete 270 rows

I checked this query in relay log file and they were there but not executed. also i turn of slave_skip_error and it does not raise any error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How did you setup Source - Replica? Post the show slave status. It has never occured something like this without having an error on the replica

Comment: Was it a single 3500-row delete statement?  Or 3500 single-row deletes?